# MongoTemplate deterministic order in update query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-mongodb

I am using MongoTemplate in my Spring Batch writer, and I would like to use an `$addToSet` operator to push my elements in an array only if they do not exist yet.
I see in the Mongodb documentation that the `$addToSet` works **only if the fields are in the same order**.

So my question is: does MongoTemplate convert my pojo into Bson document always in the same order?

I found this converter in MongoTemplate's code (`MappingMongoConverter`), and to me the loop is not deterministic :

```
private void writeProperties(Bson bson, MongoPersistentEntity<?> entity, PersistentPropertyAccessor<?> accessor,
        DocumentAccessor dbObjectAccessor, @Nullable MongoPersistentProperty idProperty) {

    // Write the properties
    for (MongoPersistentProperty prop : entity) {

        if (prop.equals(idProperty) || !prop.isWritable()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (prop.isAssociation()) {
            writeAssociation(prop.getRequiredAssociation(), accessor, dbObjectAccessor);
            continue;
        }

        Object value = accessor.getProperty(prop);

        if (value == null) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!conversions.isSimpleType(value.getClass())) {
            writePropertyInternal(value, dbObjectAccessor, prop);
        } else {
            writeSimpleInternal(value, bson, prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I see in the Mongodb documentation that the $addToSet works only if the fields are in the same order."_ - I see that there is _no such rule_ mentioned in the MongoDB Manual. `$addToSet` update operator adds an element to an array field _only_ if the element doesnt exist.

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/ : _"If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields and values and the fields are in **the same order**. As such, field order matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element."_

Comment: That is for the scenario where the array field element is a sub-document (or object).

Comment: Yes it is my case, the array contains documents, that's why I'm asking about MongoTemplate "marshalling" order. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Mongo `@Field` annotation allow to set explicitly the order of each field.

Some of my POJOs have 1000 fields, it's a laborious solution in my case but is is a solution.
If someone knows an easier way, I will be grateful :)

source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Field.html